# `<main>': private method `initialize' called for #<Blockchain::Wallet:0x00000001932f28> (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Iam working on Blockchain.info wallet ruby, followed the steps as in the doc https://github.com/Tolsi/blockchain-wallet-ruby/blob/master/lib/blockchain/wallet.rb . Added wallet object to wallet.rb file and used ruby wallet.rb command to run the file, getting this `error`': private method `initialize' called for #<Blockchain::Wallet:0x00000001932f28> (NoMethodError)`. How to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 4):

Are you calling:

```
Blockchain::Wallet.initialize(opts)
```

You should be calling:

```
Blockchain::Wallet.new(opts)
```

Ruby classes define their constructor methods with `initialize`, but you instantiate them with `new`.